# Is there any way to spawn the Enderdragon in Minecraft without mods of any kind?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need a way to spawn the Enderdragon boss mob in Minecraft without mods. I cannot get mods, heck, I can't even get texture packs, and I wan't to have an epic battle between Withers and Enderdragons in Vanilla Minecraft. I don't play in a snapshot and I don't have the Horse update.

Comment: There is no way to do it without using modifications or external tools. I suggest you to buy Minecraft if that's the reason why you don't have 1.6 yet.

Comment: @MBraedley as I read it, that other one's about getting him to reappear in The End, this one's about spawning him anywhere, any time, and even seems to be looking to spawn more than one, which is quite a different thing to go about doing.

Comment: I don't think it is exactly a duplicate though...

Comment: If anyone stumbles on this question in the future, I too think it was wrongly labelled a duplicate, just of the wrong question. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348463/how-do-i-successfully-summon-the-ender-dragon-using-commands is a good resource on spawning working ember dragon(s) at-will.  Also see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220465/i-cant-find-the-end-portal and https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/175309/where-is-my-end-portal for info on the regular method of spawning the initial Ender Dragon.

Comment: Also, since this question has a couple of quality answers, and has the highest view count, perhaps it should be merged, not closed. Or maybe we need a meta-question about creating enderdragons in general, since there are apparently 3 ways to do so, and several more questions about corner cases.

Answer (score 6):

#### Use commands

As of Minecraft 1.7 you can spawn in mobs using this command:

```
/summon <Entity-Name> <x> <y> <z> [Data-Tag]
```

By typing `/summon EnderDragon` into the Minecraft chat you would spawn in an EnderDragon at your coordinates.

As for Minecraft 1.6 and lower - there is no way to do it without using modifications or external tools.

If you are okay with a 1v1 between the EnderDragon and the Wither Boss you can just spawn in a Wither in the End.

```
WS WS WS    // (3 Wither Skulls)
SS SS SS    // (3 Soul Sands)
-- SS --    // (1 Soul Sand in the Middle / -- = Air)
```

Comment: I just haven't updated it to the horse update, but it's pretty current.

Comment: @MasterHalo937 As I said, spawning the enderdragon in versions below 1.7 is not possible without using mods or tools. The horse update is 1.6, so it's not possible there either.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to spawn the enderdragon in vanilla without 1.7 is to just go to the end, but to do that you'll need to find it.

**Note:** if you're in survival, be sure to bring at least four soulsand and three wither skeleton heads.

If you're in survival, you'll need to gather enderpearls and blaze powder to get eyes of ender. Then you need to throw them, and follow them in that direction. (if you're in creative you can just get them out of your inventory)

Once the eyes of ender start falling, instead of going in some other direction, dig directly down where it fell. After some digging, you should find stone bricks, and directly below that will be a stronghold. In strongholds, there is usually a room designated to the ender portal, which has a silverfish spawner and lots of lava. Use (right click) on the portal frame (what's around the biggest plot of lava) with the ender eyes and when all of their buttons are up, a black portal will appear within the frame. Jump in!

There will be an enderdragon in the end. (where you just got teleported)

Use the heads you brought with you/search "wither skeleton" in your creative inventory to get wither skeleton heads, and use the soulsand with it, in this pattern: (h = wither skeleton head, s = soulsand)

```
hhh
sss
 s
```

After building this (not in a crafting table, in the world) a wither will spawn. Have fun!

Comment: Have fun **dying** (If you're in survival).