# I can't find the end portal

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm playing Minecraft on Xbox 360 and I can't find the [End Portal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_portal). I have tried every trick I can think of, including the xray glitch, and recreating the world in Creative mode to dig out the entire stronghold and the surrounding areas. I have found nothing and I am totally lost on where it could be.

The seed is `1833758535681455132`

Comment: Have you tried to use more Eyes of Ender from within the fortress to pinpoint the spot where the Ender Portal is? When it floats in place when you throw it, dig up and down from where it hovers and you should find the portal.

Answer (score 8):

The conventional method for finding an End Portal is to use [Eyes of Ender](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Eye_of_Ender) (Combine Blaze Powder with an Ender Pearl). When used, they will float up in the direction of the closest End Portal, then after a few seconds, either fall back down, or break.

Once you get within a certain range of an End Portal, the Eyes of Ender will then float down toward the ground. This is where you can start digging, as the Eye of Ender will (generally) indicate you are directly above the portal.

As for using the "x-ray glitch" and "digging out the entire area", an End Portal is a rare occurrence. If you managed to find one near your spawn (say, within 64 chunks) you'd be incredibly lucky.

Answer (score -2):

Remember not all strong holds have portals, and depending of the seed these structures might be thousands of blocks apart.

Might want to try another Seed: -1075018877
go/teleport to  coordinates: -863, 62, 1115